# Cannot connect to home wireless internet

Tags: 12.10, wireless, networking

I have been using Linux Mint for the past few months and I decided to switch back to Ubuntu. After doing so I have run into a peculiar error.

I had previously been able to connect to the Internet with my laptop, but as of now, I cannot, as it refuses to connect to the wireless network I use.

It will connect to other wireless networks, as that's how I'm posting this, but I cannot seem to connect to my home network.